# Result in a separate page in R shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I want when I click on the search button show the result on a separate page, not on the same page.
I have tried two codes the first one:

UI:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  mainPanel(

    div(align = "center", style="margin-left:500px",
        radioButtons("typeInput", "Extract tweets by: ",list("Hashtag" = "hashtag", "Twitter Username"= "username"),inline=T),
          textInput("hashtagInput", "Enter search string","", placeholder = "input search string"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.typeInput == 'username'",
          textInput("usernameInput", "Username", placeholder = "input username")),
        sliderInput("numberInput", "Select number of tweets",min = 0, max = 3000, value = 100),
          br(),
        actionButton("goButton", "Search", icon("twitter"),
                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7"),
        uiOutput("pageStub")
    )))
```

server:

```
server = function(input, output){
  data = eventReactive(input$goButton, {

    if (input$typeInput == "hashtag") {
      tweetOutput = searchThis(search_string = input$hashtagInput,
                                      number.of.tweets = input$numberInput)} 
    else if (input$typeInput == "username") {
      tweetOutput = userTL(user.name = input$usernameInput,number.of.tweets = input$numberInput)}
    else {}
    library(twitteR)
    df.tweets = data.frame(tweetOutput)
    tweetOutput = df.tweets})
  uiOutput(
    output$pageStub <- renderUI(
      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          renderDataTable({data()}, options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 30, 50), pageLength = 5))))))}
```

but it shows the result on the same page as shown here

[image]

the second code I tried shinyBS library but I think the window is too small

UI:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  mainPanel(

    div(align = "center", style="margin-left:500px",
        radioButtons("typeInput", "Extract tweets by: ",list("Hashtag" = "hashtag", "Twitter Username"= "username"),inline=T),
          textInput("hashtagInput", "Enter search string","", placeholder = "input search string"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.typeInput == 'username'",
          textInput("usernameInput", "Username", placeholder = "input username")),
        sliderInput("numberInput", "Select number of tweets",min = 0, max = 3000, value = 100),
          br(),
        actionButton("goButton", "Search", icon("twitter"),
                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7"),

        bsModal("modalExample", "Your result", "goButton", size = "large",dataTableOutput("tweetTable"))
    )))
```

server:

```
server = function(input, output)
{
  data = eventReactive(input$goButton, {

    if (input$typeInput == "hashtag") 
    {
      tweetOutput = searchThis(search_string = input$hashtagInput,
                                      number.of.tweets = input$numberInput)
    } 
    else if (input$typeInput == "username") 
    {
      tweetOutput = userTL(user.name = input$usernameInput,number.of.tweets = input$numberInput)
    }
    else {}
    library(twitteR)
    df.tweets = data.frame(tweetOutput)
    tweetOutput = df.tweets

  })

 output$tweetTable =renderDataTable({data()}, options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 30, 50), pageLength = 5))
}
```

as shown here:

[image]

and here is the search function that I called:

```
searchThis = function(search_string,number.of.tweets = 100)
{
  search_tweets(search_string,n = number.of.tweets, lang = "en")
}


userTL = function(user.name,number.of.tweets = 100)
{
  userTimeline(user.name,n = number.of.tweets)
}
```

is there any other way to do this?
thank you

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with "separate page" ? In shiny you can work with panels, collapsible objects, popup windows ... There are lots of possibilities

Comment: my app will show the data table when I click the button, but I don't need it to show the data table on the same page after the search button. I need it on another page, it's more like popup window which I tried but its too small, I need the window to full all the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use modals, you can modify the width so it's full-screen with the following line in the UI :

```
tags$head(tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:100%; overflow-x: scroll;}"))
# width :100% enables you to choose the width of the modal, it could be 95%,50% ...
# overflow-x:scroll displays a horizontal scrollbar if the content is too large for the modal
```

You UI would be

```
ui = fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  mainPanel(

  tags$head(tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:100%; overflow-x: scroll;}")),

    div(align = "center", style="margin-left:500px",
        radioButtons("typeInput", "Extract tweets by: ",list("Hashtag" = "hashtag", "Twitter Username"= "username"),inline=T),
          textInput("hashtagInput", "Enter search string","", placeholder = "input search string"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.typeInput == 'username'",
          textInput("usernameInput", "Username", placeholder = "input username")),
        sliderInput("numberInput", "Select number of tweets",min = 0, max = 3000, value = 100),
          br(),
        actionButton("goButton", "Search", icon("twitter"),
                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7"),

        bsModal("modalExample", "Your result", "goButton", size = "large",dataTableOutput("tweetTable"))
    )))
```

Comment: I got this error:  ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: It must be a parenthesis or bracket problem but I don't see where.

Comment: Great, it is closed to what you expected ?

Comment: no I mean maybe the problem with tags$head part, it's still small

Comment: thannnnk you its work I solve the problem by reading this post   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450011/r-error-in-taghead-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable